# add days and hours in date/time field and get the updated date/time in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-manipulation

I would like to provide the ability for users to submit a `datetime` value, along with values representing additional days/hours, and then store the `datetime` that results from adding the two in a mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in PHP, this should help:

```
$datetime = '2010-02-11 12:00:00';

$days = '5';
$hours = '3';

$new_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+$days days $hours hours", strtotime($datetime)));

echo $new_datetime; # Will output '2010-02-16 15:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

to add an interval (a day or several hours) to datetime, you can use the [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in PHP, you can use mktime, adding the additional time / date values as you require:

```
$time = mktime($hours + $extra_hours, $minutes, $seconds, $months + $extra_months, $days, $years);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

Comment: What if $hours + $extra_hours adds up to more than 24 - does mktime deal with that correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does. It will also handle rollover for the other parameters.