# PHP- how to retrieve expire datetime

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I need to retrieve the expire datetime starting from the current datetime + some time.

The example is:

```
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$expire_time = 24;// 1 day in hours as int() for example ;)

$expire_datetime = date($current_datetime + $expire_time); //don't know how to do this in Y-m-d H:m:s format!!
```

I would like to write down an helper lib starting from this script.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985818/php-date-time-current-time-add-minutes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242601/add-days-and-hours-in-date-time-field-and-get-the-updated-date-time-in-php-using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811609/php-add-two-hours-to-date-variable

Comment: or [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$expire_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:m:s',strtotime("NEXT DAY"));
```

or

```
 $expire_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:m:s',strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

Comment: wow, how can i extend this to 1week or 1 month or 1 year for example?

Comment: change according to need strtotime("next week")

Comment: @Ispuk or you can use  strtotime("+1 week")

Comment: is it ok to use NEXT MONTH or NEXT WEEK or NEXT YEAR or NEXT DAY ?... ineed both them :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$newdate = strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date('y-m-d',$newdate)
echo $newdate;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php - "Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2."

Comment: can i extend this to 1week or 1 month or 1 year for example?

Comment: he asked a minimal let him check this in manual .and he hasnt mentioned php version